# My wireless card doesnot support AP mode. Is it the end?

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, hot-spot

When I run `iwconfig`, it doesnot list AP under supported features. My aim is to start a WiFi hotspot with my laptop. So is that it? All hopes lost?

It is to be added that my friend who has the same card, but runs Windows can do it. Also my search for a driver which supports AP turned out to be futile. Now all hopes lost?

Comment: You can setup an ad-hoc mode. But phones do not support it. You can replace this card with another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can buy some wifi usb dongle that support AP mode.

  It's a matter of searching with some */search engine HERE/*. May be 1
  hour of your time.

  /me bought the *TL-WN725N* for my *raspberry pi*, but I won't recommend
  it for you since it needs a special **hostapd** version and some more
  work...
- Or you can even replace the wifi card of your laptop. Most of the
  time it's easy to do.
- Or you can even ask *broadcom* to give us linux driver on par with the windows one.

  *bcmwl-kernel-broadcom* driver is supposed to support *monitor mode* but `echo 1 > /proc/brcm_monitor0` just **freeze** my laptop here. **Hard reboot needed**. Or for unkown reason to me, wifi AP on channel 13 are not visible by the driver (even though `crda` is configured corectly)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/387780/cant-change-brcm-monitor0-in-proc