# cannot edit /proc/brcm_monitor0

Tags: wireless

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 on a Macbook air whose airport uses the Broadcom BCM4360. I'm usung the wl driver now and it is working, but I cannot put the device into monitor mode. I've read that I must add a 1 to the /proc/brcm_monitor0 file but this causes my system to crash. I would appreciate any help. thanks

---

Thanks @Liso, for the help. But I get this error when trying to compile:

```
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-27-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  LD      /home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_alloc_linux_if’:
/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1348:64: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
  dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof(priv_link_t), intf_name, ether_setup);
                                                                ^
/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1348:8: error: ‘alloc_netdev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof(priv_link_t), intf_name, ether_setup);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1348:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_dump_ver’:
/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2041:3: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
   __DATE__, __TIME__, EPI_VERSION_STR);
   ^~~~~~~~
/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2041:13: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
   __DATE__, __TIME__, EPI_VERSION_STR);
             ^~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
Makefile:1489: recipe for target '_module_/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/chris/broadcom/hybrid] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-27-generic'
Makefile:136: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instructions from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/398653/253251)

> > 1. Download driver source (6.30.223.141) from Broadcom
>
> ```
>     wget http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_141.tar.gz
>     tar xvzf hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_141.tar.gz
> ```
>
> > 2. DO NOT APPLY LINUX 3.10 UBUNTU PATCH. Apply http://ix.io/9DV patch only.
>
> ```
>     wget http://ix.io/9DV
>     cd hybrid
>     patch -i ../9DV -p1
> ```
>
> > 3. Compile the driver.
> >
> >    ```
> >    make
> >    ```
>
> 4. Testing the driver.
>
>    ```
>    sudo rmmod wl
>    sudo insmod ./wl.ko
>    ```
> 5. Enable monitor mode.
>
>    ```
>    sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /proc/brcm_monitor0"
>    ```
>
> source:
>   http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/broadcom-wl/?setlang=de&comments=all

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I get this error when trying to compile: